# What happens if I add a collaborator to a private GitHub project who does not have a private plan?

Tags: github

I am curious if I can add a collaborator for just watching my project without giving him the rights to make it public, yet.

So, the current situation would be:
- I created a private GitHub repo that I don't want to have public yet
- I have a colleague who does not have a paid GitHub account
- I want to add this colleague as "watcher" only without exposing the project to the public yet

Would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you trust your collaborator to not clone the repo and post it publically, yes you can add them as a collaborator to see the private repo.

From [Github's docs](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-add-a-collaborator): "All collaborators must have GitHub accounts. It's easy to sign up, and even accounts on the free plan can collaborate on private repositories"